# concurrect oprating with limit on thread count in a infinity loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, deadlock, concurrent-programming

I write an infinity loop for pulling from queue(RabbitMQ) and processing each pulled item in concurrent threads with limited count on running threads.
Now i want a solution for make a limit in thread execution count.see an example of my loop:

```
public class ThreadWorker<T>
{
    public List<T> _lst;
    private int _threadCount;
    private int _maxThreadCount;
    public ThreadWorker(List<T> lst, int maxThreadCount)
    {
        _lst = lst;
        _maxThreadCount = maxThreadCount;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var i = 0;
        while (i < _lst.Count)
        {
            i++;
            var pull = _lst[i];

            Process(pull);
        }
    }

    public void Process(T item)
    {
        if (_threadCount > _maxThreadCount)
        {
            //wait any opration be done 
            // How to wait for one thread?

            Interlocked.Decrement(ref _threadCount);
        }

        var t = new Thread(() => Opration(item));

        t.Start();

        Interlocked.Increment(ref _threadCount);
    }

    public void Opration(T item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

Notice that when i use a semaphore for limitation, Start() method don't wait for all running threads. my loop should after running threads with _maxThreadCount, be wait until release a thread and then push new thread for concurrent processing.

Comment: My problem make with an infinity parallel.For with ParallelOption.maxdegreeofparallelism but i don't want use it.I want manage threads in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use *Semaphore* this way to control the number of threads:

```
public class ThreadWorker<T>
{
    SemaphoreSlim _sem = null;
    List<T> _lst;

    public ThreadWorker(List<T> lst, int maxThreadCount)
    {
        _lst = lst;
        _sem = new SemaphoreSlim(maxThreadCount);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var i = 0;
        while (i < _lst.Count)
        {
            i++;
            var pull = _lst[i];
            _sem.Wait(); /*****/
            Process(pull);
        }
    }

    public void Process(T item)
    {
        var t = new Thread(() => Opration(item));
        t.Start();
    }

    public void Opration(T item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        _sem.Release(); /*****/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when we use semaphore or semaphoreSlim, Start() method don't wait for finished all running threading.Have you any idea for this problem?

Comment: @Arash then add `for (int i = 0; i < maxThreadCount; i++) _sem.Wait();` to the end of `Start`